# What's the average case time complexity of the following algorithm for finding kth smallest element?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, heap, quicksort

Algorithm for finding k-th smallest number in an array

1. Build a Max-Heap MH of the first k elements (arr[0] to arr[k-1]) of the given array. O(k)
2. For each element, after the k’th element (arr[k] to arr[n-1]), compare it with root of MH.

   a) If the element is less than the root then make it root and call heapify for MH*

   b) *Else ignore it.*

   // The step 2 is O((n-k)*logk)
3. Finally, root of the MH is the kth smallest element.

Time complexity of this solution is O(k + (n-k)*Logk)*

If not the exact value, can you tell the rough range of this ? I'm assuming the best case is when k=n, then time=O(n) and worst case is when k=n/2, then O(n)=nlogn.

Answer (score 0):

The *worst case* for this algorithm is, as you say O(k + (n-k)*log(k)). We say it's O(n log k) in general, because that's the dominant term. The average time is generally acknowledged to be O(n log k).

The algorithm's real-world running time is dominated by two things: the value of k, and the order in which items are presented. In general, for a given value of n, real-world running time increases as k increases. But there are special cases.

Remember that the O(log n) heap insertion is only incurred when a number is smaller than the largest number already on the heap. That is, you have a loop that looks like:

```
for each remaining item
    if item < top of heap
        replace top of heap with this item
```

If the items in the list are in ascending order, then you'll build a heap of the first k items, and you'll *never* modify the heap again. Conversely, if the list is in descending order, every item will be added to the heap.

I did some pretty extensive analysis of this and other selection algorithms a few years back, and wrote about it in my blog. See [When theory meets practice](http://blog.mischel.com/2011/10/25/when-theory-meets-practice/).